# what does ^await (with the caret symbol) mean in compiled JS?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, transpiler

I'm looking through some compiled JS, built with babel from JS (NOT from typescript) and some of the output has caret symbols in.

```
       const expertForFromToken = ^await utils_JsonWebTokenStorage__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_13__["default"].getTokenKey("expertFor");
```

This code is giving me some weird errors and wondering if there is something similar to *yield and generators for async/await transpiling.

As far as I can tell that should be a [BitWise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.5E_%28Bitwise_XOR%29)

[image: compiled]

[image: original]

Comment: Looks like a pointer to me. Especially when it's purple

Comment: Yes, async/await should get transpiled into something using regenerator-runtime for targets that don't natively support it.

Comment: "As far as I can tell that should be a BitWise OR" ... actually a bitwise XOR, but where it is does not make sense at all - in fact it would be a syntax error

Comment: `>` to the left points at the line, `^` below points at the column.

Comment: When the other way round it is XOR, eg `x ^= y` is `x = x^y`

Comment: @Ry- you're right, it's just an indicator. can accept as answer if you want the karma :D